# JRuby Savon Ntlm Authentication (Works in Ruby but fails in JRuby)

Tags: ruby, authentication, jruby, ntlm

I am trying to consume a web service using ntlm authentication. The following code works in Ruby

```
        client = Savon.client(wsdl:"http://xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx.asmx?WSDL",ntlm: ["user", "pass"]) 
        response = client.call(:does_entry_id_exist, message: {
                                  :server =>'xxxxxx',
                                  :entryID =>'xxxxxx'
                                  }).to_s
```

But when I try executing it in jRuby it gives me an Authentication error

```
Install the httpi-ntlm gem for experimental NTLM support
```

I have installed the gem and have included the same in my code but still it bombs out. Can anyone please help.

Comment: I installed 'httpi-ntlm' gem and removed 'httpi' gem and got it working. But now I am running into a SOAP 401 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar issue, and unfortunately I'm stuck with JRuby 1.6.8.
We had to drop Savon and use:
pyu-ntlm-http gem with httpi-ntlm to finally get NTLM authentication to work:

https://rubygems.org/gems/pyu-ntlm-http

http://rubydoc.info/gems/pyu-ntlm-http/0.1.3.1/frames

```
request = HTTPI::Request.new
request.url = "http://WebserviceURL"
request.auth.ntlm "username","password"
request.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
request.headers["SOAPAction"] = "action"
request.body = formatted_soap_body
response = HTTPI.post(request)
```